# Конструктор класса и объекты

Tags: javascript, объекты, наследование, прототипное-наследование

Вот задание:

- Создать класс Person для создания объектов со свойствами name, age, job конструктор класса должен принимать одноимённые аргументы
- Добавить метод getInfo() который возвращает console.log(`Person info: {переменная name}, age: {переменная age}, job: {переменная job}` );
- Создать массив Data = [['John', 23, 'programmer'], ['Alisa', 34, 'yandex'], ['Bob', 30, 'manager'], ['Bill', 45, 'CEO']]
- Создать и наполнить массив Users из объектов создаваемых на основании класса Person при помощи цикла используя массив Data
- Вывести результат в консоль
- Вызвать метод getInfo у каждого из объектов в массиве при помощи цикла (нужно предварительно создать массив)
- Вывести результат в консоль

Я его наполовину решила, сбилась на пункте

> - Создать и наполнить массив Users из объектов создаваемых на основании класса Person при помощи цикла используя массив Data

Мое решение в консоль выводит просто отдельный массив Data, не понимаю как связать два объекта

```
class Person {
        constructor(name, age, job) {
            this.name = name
            this.age = age
            this.job = job
        }
        getInfo() {
            console.log(`Person info: ${this.name}, age: ${this.age}, job: ${this.job} `);
        }
    }
    const Data = [
        ['John', 23, 'programmer'], ['Alisa', 34, 'yandex'], ['Bob', 30, 'manager'], ['Bill', 45, 'CEO']
    ]

    const User = new Person()
    for (let i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
        console.log(User[i] = Data[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Person {
  constructor(name, age, job) {
    this.name = name
    this.age = age
    this.job = job
  }
  getInfo() {
    console.log(`Person info: ${this.name}, age: ${this.age}, job: ${this.job} `);
  }
}
const Data = [
  ['John', 23, 'programmer'],
  ['Alisa', 34, 'yandex'],
  ['Bob', 30, 'manager'],
  ['Bill', 45, 'CEO']
]


const Users = [];
for (let i = 0; i < Data.length; i++) {
  Users.push(new Person(...Data[i]));
}
Users.forEach(user => user.getInfo());
```